# Согласование сказуемого с подлежащим "ты"

Tags: согласование, род

Есть ли какие-то нормы и рекомендации согласования по роду сказуемого с подлежащим "ты", когда пол субъекта не ясен (например, в массовой рассылке) и перефразировать никак не получается? Особенно буду благодарна ссылкам.

- Что ты делал вчера?
- Что ты делал(а) вчера?
- Что ты делал/делала вчера?
- ...

Не нравится ни мужской без вариантов, ни забор из скобок и слешей...

Answer (score 2):

Убрать фамильярное "ты", только так.

*Что Вы делали вчера?*

Однако плакатные фразы "[Ты записался добровольцем?](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D1%8B_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%81%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BC%3F)" и "Ты чем помог фронту?" подразумевают обращение к обоим полам.